# Парсинг википедии

Tags: python, парсер

Мне нужно распарсить все статьи русской википедии за все время и за последний год.
С помощью каких инструментов можно сделать это наиболее удобно в питоне?

---

С парсингом всей википедии разобрался. Трудность вызывает сбор статей именно за последний год.

Comment: Думаю, будет интересно: http://scrapy.org/

Comment: [grab](https://habrahabr.ru/post/173509/) неплох. Очень прост в использовании и эффективен.

Comment: А вы авторизованы википедией для этого? [Правила](https://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use#4._Refraining_from_Certain_Activities) говорят: «you may not engage in such activities on our sites [...] Engaging in automated uses of the site that are abusive or disruptive of the services and have not been approved by the Wikimedia community»

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Загружать все вручную или с помощью API - это тупик, статей очень и очень много и у Википедии есть какой-то порог запросов в секунду, то есть в тыщу потоков, забив весь канал скачать не получится. Есть [дампы со всеми статьями на любом языке](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/). База эта представляет собой архив, в котором гигантский XML, содержащий все статьи и какие-то метаданные. Информация не то чтобы самая-самая свежая, но должно хватить для любых задач. Однако есть проблема - статьи в дампе написаны на Wiki шаблоне, однако есть парсеры этих шаблонов. Неидеальны, но жить можно. Есть нет желания писать свое супер-крутое решение с нуля, можно взять готовенькое - в [`gensim`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/)(довольно крутая штука, кстати) есть встроенный простенький парсер. И [примерчики](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html), ясное дело.

Answer (score 2):

У Wikipedia вроде есть своё [API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) и [модуль на Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia/) для доступа к нему.

Comment: Да, посмотрел его. Нашел, как ограничить временной промежуток, но не нашел, как вытащить все статьи.